# Is there any way to avoid some bugs appeared when drag the element including span tag using "dragselect" module?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, drag-and-drop

I'm using "dragselect" module for dragging and selecting.
What I want to do is that select the items by mouse dragging and drag the selected items.
On the side of selecting the items by dragging, there is no problem, it works well.
But when I drag the selected items from one place to another, unexpected bug happens.
For example, there are three button items as following:

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Drag & Select</title>
    <script src="https://dragselect.com/v2/ds.min.js"></script>
    <link href="style.css"  rel="stylesheet"/>
</head>
<body>
<div id="container">
    <button type="button" class="item one">item 1</button>
    <button type="button" class="item two"><span>item 2</span></button>
    <button type="button" class="item three">item 3</button>
</div>
<div id="root"></div>
<script src="example.js" type="application/javascript"/>
</body>
</html>
```

style.css

```
* { user-select: none; }

html, body {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}

#container {
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05);
    border: 5px solid red;
    overflow: auto;
    height: calc(100vh - 10px);
}

.item {
    z-index: -1;
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    position: absolute;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    color: white;
    border: 0;
    background: hsla(320, 90%, 50%, 1);
}

.item:focus {
    border: 1px solid blue;
}

.item.one {
    top: 100px;
    left: 100px;
}

.item.two {
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
}

.item.three {
    top: 200px;
    left: 500px;
}

.ds-selected {
    outline: 3px solid black;
    outline-offset: 3px;
    color: black;
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

example.js

```
let ds = new DragSelect({
  selectables: document.getElementsByClassName('item'),
  area: document.getElementById('container')
});
```

After selecting 3 buttons by dragging, then we can drag them.
When we drag them by clicking and dragging item1 or item3 which doesn't include span tag, there is no problem, 3 items will be dragging well.
but when we drag them by clicking and dragging item2 which includes span tag, more exactly, when click and drag the string "item2", unexpected bug will be happened.

If anybody can help me to solve this issue, that would be really thankful.
Best regards